# Client Error trying to do JsonObjectRequest with Android Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to do an HTTP PUT with JSON to a service that needs HTTP Basic Auth, but I keep getting client errors. I do this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, payOp.getURL(), payOp.getJson(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Response " + response.toString());
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error " + error.toString());
             Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error ", error);
         }
     }){
         @Override
         public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
             HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

             ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = ApplicationSettings.getInstance();
             String username = applicationSettings.mMID;
             String password = applicationSettings.mAPIPassword;

             String creds = String.format("%s:%s",username, password);
             String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
             Log.i("jsonObjectRequest","Authorization is: " + auth);
             params.put("Authorization", auth);
             return params;
         }
     };

     queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

And I get back:

```
2019-05-04 17:52:40.158 7430-7430/com.amex.gatewaydemotr5 I/jsonObjectRequest: Error 
    com.android.volley.ClientError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm making the creds string correct (I have another app written in node.js that works to compare the output to) but I don't get a lot of output from Volley for an error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is there some way to get more detail out of Volley on the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, figured it out. It was a problem with my URL & Data, but the main thing was I didn't understand how to parse the errors, for anyone who needs to know there's a networkResponse object on the error that has statusCode and data parameters. The server messages are there. The data parameter comes back as a byte array, so you have to wrap it in a string object to see the results.

Once I understood that I could get the messages back I needed and fix the problem, here's the code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, payOp.getURL(), payOp.getJson(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Response " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error, Status Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "URL: " + payOp.getURL());
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Payload: " + payOp.getJson().toString());
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Net Response to String: " + error.networkResponse.toString());
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error bytes: " + new String(error.networkResponse.data));

    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = ApplicationSettings.getInstance();
        String username = applicationSettings.mMID;
        String password = applicationSettings.mAPIPassword;

        String creds = String.format("%s:%s",username, password);
        String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Log.i("jsonObjectRequest","Authorization is: " + auth);
        params.put("Authorization", auth);
        return params;
    }
};
```

The important part is this:

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error, Status Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "URL: " + payOp.getURL());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Payload: " + payOp.getJson().toString());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Net Response to String: " + error.networkResponse.toString());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error bytes: " + new String(error.networkResponse.data));

}
```